# Utilizar $diacriticSensitive con match en Mongo

Tags: mongodb

estoy tratando de realizar una búsqueda en un documento de mongo que tiene guardado en el nombre la palabra energético, realizo la consulta de la siguiente forma:

```
    {'$match': {
             'name': {
             '$regex': '.*energetico.*',
             '$options': 'i'
                    }
              }}
```

Pero no obtengo resultado hasta que le pongo el acento, busque en la documentación de Mongo y me apareció $diacriticSensitive, pero cuando lo coloque en mi código me sale el error:
        'unknown operator: $diacriticSensitive'

Existe alguna forma de realizar la búsqueda sin importar si tiene acento para que me pueda regresar un resultado?

Answer (score 1):

Algo parecido me paso a mi pero en mi caso solo necesitaba buscar una palabra sin contar con los acentos sobre un texto, en mi caso lo solucione utilizando el metodo '$text' de MongoDB. Te muestro un ejemplo.

Suponiendo que tenemos una colección 'poblaciones' y queremos buscar una palabra sobre los campos de 'provincia' y 'población' tendríamos que realizar la siguiente consulta:

```
db.getCollection('poblaciones').find({$text: {$search: "almeria", $diacriticSensitive: false}})
```

Y para que MongoDD sepa en que campo tiene que buscar tendríamos que crear un indice con los campos de búsqueda:

```
{ "poblacion": "text", "provincia": "text"}
```

Enlaces de interés:

[MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/index.html)

[Mongoose text search with diacriticSensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35670455/mongoose-text-search-with-)

Espero que con esta info puedas solucionar tu problema.

Saludos